# For $f$: $\mathbb Z^+ \rightarrow \mathbb Z^+$, is $f(x) = \sqrt n$ a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

This question is from a book provided by my basic math class.

For $f$: $\mathbb Z^+ \rightarrow \mathbb Z^+$, where $f(x) = \sqrt n$

Is it a function?

My first thought was that as $x\in \mathbb Z^+$, for all positive integers, there will be exactly one assignment of $x$ to an image $y \in \mathbb Z^+$.

However, the book stated that the answer is no, without any justifications.

May I ask why is this so?

Comment: 2 is an element of the domain, but is $f(2)$ an element of the co-domain?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt n $ or  $\sqrt x $  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression
$$
f : \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+, \quad f(n) = \sqrt n,
$$
does not describe a function.

This is because the expression is erronerous: first it is stating that $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, but $f(2) = \sqrt 2$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

---

**Your mistake:**

> there will be exactly one assignment of $x$ to an image $y\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

This is not right. The image $y=f(x)$ is not always in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: It is, however, a partial function from $\mathbb Z^+ \rightarrow \mathbb Z^+$. The confusion may be arising because most calculus courses allow the term "function" to include partial functions like $\mathrm{arcsin}(x)$.

Comment: The question Weitin meant to ask is the following: *is the mathematical expression $f : \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}: n \mapsto \sqrt n$ well formed and meaningful?* The answer is no. How can "partial functions" help reduce confusion? Are partial functions really taught in calculus classes?

Comment: Yes, all the time. $\exp(x)$ is a function from $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, while $\mathrm{arcsin(x)}$ is a partial function from $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. However, most calculus courses will not draw this distinction and refer to both as functions, saying that $\arcsin(x)$ is undefined for $|x| > 1$.

Comment: This answer is false. $f$ is a total function (since the definition domain = domain) from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, but it is not **onto** because the range of $f $ is a subset of co-domain $\mathcal{Z}$. I am not sure what book you are refering to but I do recommend you review the second chapter of **Discrete Math** by Rosen.

Answer (score 2):

I think we have to make the distinction between the domain of definition of $f$ and the fact that $f$ is a function because it assigns at most $1$ image element for any input.

For instance $f_1 : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R,\quad f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Is $f_1$ a function ? You could say yes but domain is not $\mathbb R$ but $\mathbb R^+$, or no because you consider the definition should explicitely state the correct domain.

Yet, we often see such erroneous definitions in exercises, along with the question : *"what is the domain of definition of the function $f$ defined by ... ?"*. It is really common to speak of a function over a general set without expliciting its domain at first.

I think it is the same here, the statement $f_2 : \mathbb N\to\mathbb N,\quad f_2(n)=\sqrt n$ requires to be valid that we precise the correct domain of definition of $f_2$, which is $A=\{n^2\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Now $f_2 : A\to\mathbb N,\quad f(n)=\sqrt n$ is correct.

Be aware also that $f_3 : \mathbb C\to\mathbb C,\quad f(z)=\sqrt z$ seems valid, because the domain is respected, the codomain too, but $f_3$ is not a function this time because it is possible to assign $2$ values for any input $z$. And it is not possible to make a rational choice that would respect all arithmetic properties (for instance $\sqrt{\vphantom{b} a}\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$ may fail).

To conclude, I think we have to separate in our definition of the function the cases of $f_1,f_2$ which are indeed functions but whose domain of definition should be precised, and the case of $f_3$ which is multivalued.

In first case it is only an abuse of language, while in the late case this is a more fundamental issue.

Comment: When you write down something like "$f(x)$", it presupposes that $f$ is a function. Otherwise, the expression "$f(x)$" is already meaningless. Students should be encouraged to outgrow the question "is $x \mapsto f(x)$ a function?" because it is not a mathematical question. The only real questions here are: "does the statment $x \mapsto f(x)$ makes sense?" and "is the relation $R \subset A\times A$ a function?"

Comment: In short: Your answer addresses a non-mathematical question, while the real problem underlying Wetin's question (one of mathematical grammar) is left untouched.

Comment: I agree, and stated it is an abuse of language, but one has to remark that it is a very common one. I think it would be heavy in case where the function is complicated to not consider it because we are unable to compute the domain of definition. Instead we write $f(x)$ *whereever it is defined* and see what it brings. For instance when we study ODE, we do not know a priori the domain of definition, yet, we write and use $f(x)$. Regarding Weiting simpler problem, I thought that $f_2 : A\to N,\quad f(n)=\sqrt n$ was answering the question.

Comment: Yes, it must be good to explain this kind of standard abuse of notation. And the non-sensical question "is x \mapsto f(x)$ a function?" *is* asked in middle/high school exams... +1 for making some sense out of all this.